# Shopify Removing Hidden Products from Paginate

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a store where wholesale products are by default hidden from view for non-wholesale users.

Paginate is set to 48 products, so if there are 10 hidden products, 38 will show on the page.

Because I'm using "wholesale" in the product handle to hide them, I can't use a smart collection as you can't filter by handle.

Is there a way to exclude hidden items from paginate?

Thanks!

Comment: this issue have solution with smart collections.

Comment: Thanks, but I just updated the question to be more specific.  I can't use a smart collection because they don't allow filtering with product handle, which is how I tag the products.

Comment: Is tedious, but only with ajax could be.